# Display output of cursor

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, procedure

I wrote this procedure

```
create or replace procedure copia_telefoni2 as

cursor cur_out_tel is 
  select nome as original_list
  from parlamentari;


begin
for n_tel in cur_out_tel loop
  dbms_output.put_line(n_tel.original_list);
end loop;
end copia_telefoni2;
```

but when I run this procedure by ide or by sql*plus, the system returns me this output

> Source does not have a runnable target.

Instead, if I run in the prompt of sql*plus the query of the cursor, the system returns me a list of name. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself. In sqlplus, the first time when you run a function, you must run the instruction

> set serveroutput on;

and only then must run the instruction for lunch the procesure

> execute copia_telefoni2();

The following calls with sql*plus at the procedure can be omitted the first instruction